# Could not find the main class (on other computers)

Tags: java

I finished writing a java program and am ready to export it. I made a runnable jar from Eclipse. Running the jar works just fine on my computer, but throws the "Could not find main class" error on any other computer (including my other computer that I write Java on).

Whenever I search around for other people having the problem, it's always the same answer: Check the manifest file. I'm not seeing any problem with mine (Plus, can't imagine why it'd work on my computer but not someone else's)

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: my.quick.monster.QuickMonster
```

And I've also tried:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: my.quick.monster.QuickMonster
```

Both work for me, but not other computers.

Comment: Without knowing the jar layout and how you're running it it'll be harder to help :)

Comment: +1 for what @Dave said.  How are you trying to run the jar?  What's inside it?  Is `QuickMonster` in the root of the jar or do you have nested folders inside the jar?

Comment: JAR contains:
my/quick/monster/QuickMonster.class
my/quick/monster/RTFFilter.class
my/quick/monster/DispWindow.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

I've run it by double-clicking and through command line. Friends only ran it with double-clicking

Comment: So other people can run it?  Does that mean the problem is solved?  What dependencies does your code have?  Other libraries maybe?

Comment: No one else has had it run. They ATTEMPTED to run it via double-clicking. Anyway, I use several javax.swing and java.awt components and one instance of java.io.file

Comment: good luck men. this eclipse is so powerful and easy to use, yummy. @Pual would be happy to spend a lot of time to solve the problem of the 'simplest' solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking about the things that *might* be going wrong, here are a few other things to check:

- make sure that there are no spurious characters (tabs, spaces) at the end of the lines.
- check that the main class is actually in the JAR file with the right name.
- on the machine that works, try changing your current directory and seeing if it still works.
- check that you are *using* the same version of Java on each machine.  Run `java -version` to check.
- make sure that you are running it as an executable JAR; i.e. as `java -jar foo.jar` not as `java -cp foo.jar`.

(One theory is that the JAR is working on the one machine *in spite of* the manifest; e.g. that it is finding the class via the classpath in your CLASSPATH environment variable or something.)

---

To summarize for other folks, the OP's problem turned out to be that he had compiled his code with / for Java 7, and was trying to run the JAR on older Java installations.  That wasn't working because of the classfile version numbers.

You can compile your code so that it will run on an older version of Java, but you *need to* use the `-target` option when compiling, and you *ought to* use the -bootclasspath option to compile against an `rt.jar` from the oldest Java version.  A typical IDE will simplify this by allowing you to specify the target build platform, but it is worthwhile understanding the technical details, for cases where you are not using an IDE.

(I'm surprised that the `java` command didn't mention the classfile version number in the error message ...)

Comment: All three computers I checked had different versions. Computer it works on has 1.7.0_01, other computer has 1.6.0_25, and friend's has 1.5.0_22. Is this not going to be able to run on other versions of Java? And if so, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: @ManInBlack Did you compile it as 1.7? If so, earlier JVMs won't be able to run it because of that. Set it to compile as 1.5. That's also the kind of information it's useful to present up-front.

Comment: Worked, thanks! In my defense, I didn't know that this was even an option, much less something to pass along.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the MANIFEST.MF file contains a blank line at the end. If the `Main-Class` definition is on the very last line of the file, some class loaders ignore it.

Comment: There are a few blank lines. Through experimenting, I found it wouldn't work for me, either, without the right spaces. Seems to like having exactly 5 lines.

Answer (score -4):

Do not ever use 'eclipse-jar-worked-fine-on-my-computer'. I use maven shade jar plugin which excellently build a ready to run jar with all the dependencies, specified main class, etc.

EDIT:
What is the wrong with eclipse-builded-jar is that you won't been able to build it w/o elcipse. Maven is the common tool widely used to build packages of any kind. It's automated, and means that it can be used in CI environmet, etc. And the goal of a good developer is to write code so that it can be easily moved to CI.

However, if it's not a regular task, assuming to make just once/twice, theen, maybe, 'eclipse' solutio has also some benefits. But, I answered keeping in mind some cases of my past when people build packages in GUI just because they didn't manage to do it in maven.

So, I hope there is enough arguments for maven vs eclipse, so please stop downvote :D

Comment: Rather than suggest another tool it's better to learn the problem with his current jar.  The answer to "my jar won't run" is not always "use a maven plugin".

Comment: people should be able build their jars by not using proprietar tool which is not for example be able to run under server console. that's why I think it's totally wrong to build it using eclipse

Comment: A plugin is a tool as well.  He doesn't need another tool - he needs understanding of how Java runs code from a jar file.

Comment: Dear @Paul suggest please the way how he can put it in the under the version control for example? so that other members of team (I hope we are now talking not about 'I am write my helloworld jar and do not want to know how it is done in commercial environments'???) could be able to compile and build it too? what if they has no eclipse, and working under another IDE?? please be so good to explain your downvote

Comment: a 'plugin' is a convenient tool to build things in java. eclipse is just IDE, @Paul

Comment: I am not saying he should shun all tools.  I'm saying the answer to this very question is not another tool.

Comment: @Paul it is. It is useless knowledge - to know how Eclipse build their jars and why it was not built correctly. because people should know that there are better solution and never even trying to use it. why you did not answer about how he would place it under VC?

Comment: @Paul instead of pointing junior to the right direction you are trying to give him answers to the stupid questions...

Comment: You are aware that have yet to give any reason why a jar built by the "maven shade jar plugin" would be better than the one built by eclipse? Moreover, do you really think the simplest solution to a jar that isn't built correctly is learning maven? I like maven, but if all you want to do is build a jar file, maven is complete overkill, and a lot harder to use than the jar export from eclipse.

Comment: @meriton I gave enough reasons in the comments to my post. what about the simplicity - I believe that simplest solution is to making things right straight avay. I met enough juniors who instead of placing jar-building in the existing maven project, used to create it manually in eclipse - and just because nobody on the SO said them that's it's inappropriate way at all

Comment: @meriton if you want teach how java works, better to explain it with command line utlis - javac, jar, java, etc. But teaching eclipse instead of maven is a bad approach, it keeps lack of understanding.

Comment: @Stephen i do not think that knowledge about how one particular IDE build jarrs is the basic knowledge! the most basic ones is that one which do it in convinient ways, like ant/maven/etc. I hope I'm not alone here who think that it's better to configure one time maven pom file (it's easier and simpler for me than clicking on the forms) than every time when sources are changed - do ing the absolutely stupid monkey-job by clicking-and clicking-and clicking again... o dear god. i cannot believe